# What string can I add to my code that will make it a Q&A command with discord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'quest',
    aliases: ['q'],
    cooldown: 12,
    description: 'this offers a quest to the player',
    execute(client, message, _args, Discord){

        const quiz = [
            [      
                {
                    "question": "What is the first building that was ever considered a monument?",
                    "answers": ["The farm", "Water farm", "Farm", "farm"]
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                  "question": "Name the person who built the first carved-in mountain base.",
                  "answers": ["Richard", "Richie Rich"]
            
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                  "question": "What currency was going to be implemented but was quickly abandoned in Boring Stasis?",
                  "answers": ["Chumps", "Chump"]
            
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "question": "Who destroyed the monument in Boring Stasis?",
                    "answers": ["Shorse"]
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "question": "Name the town in A New Beginning.",
                    "answers": ["Sesame Street", "Sesamestreet", "sesame"]
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "question": "What base was built above water and is known to be the largest base in Boring Stasis?",
                    "answers": ["Doom Base", "William's base", "Will base"]
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "question": "Who was the communist in A New Beginning?",
                    "answers": ["Raimy", "NuttyHope"]
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "question": "Name the cat who lived in the cafe in A New Beginning.",
                    "answers": ["Garfield"]
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "question": "Name the monument in Boring Stasis.",
                    "answers": ["Michael B. Jordan"]
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "question": "When was the first realm created?",
                    "answers": ["January"]
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "question": "What realm was Homer first built in?",
                    "answers": ["Matthews Realm", "Matt Realm"]
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "question": "",
                    "answers": ["HARD"]
                }
            ]
            
        ]
        const item = quiz[Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.length)];
        const filter = response => {
          return item.answers.some(answer => answer.toLowerCase() === response.content.toLowerCase());
        };

        if(message.member.roles.cache.has('975976810351304784')){
        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#6655cc')
        .setTitle(`${item.question}`)
        .setAuthor({name: 'The Grinner', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})
        .setThumbnail('https://c.tenor.com/VFFI70gcJZwAAAAi/yoinkysploinky-jerma.gif')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter({text: 'Provided by The Grinner!', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})


        message.reply({embeds: [newEmbed]}, {fetchReply: true})
        .then(() => {
            message.channel.awaitMessages({filter, max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time']})
        .then(collected => {
            message.channel.send(`${collected.first().author} got the correct answer!`)
        })
        .catch(collected => {})
    })

    } else {
        const denyEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#e3263')
        .setTitle("You haven't started your campaign, use !start to get started. It's like I'm working with pinheads.")
        .setImage('https://c.tenor.com/xZFEs_q5KGEAAAAi/jerma.gif')
        .setAuthor({name: 'The Grinner', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter({text: 'Provided by The Grinner!', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})

        message.channel.send({embeds: [denyEmbed]});
    }
    }
}
```

I'm making this quest command for my discord.js bot, and I have the questions set but I don't know how to actually implement a question command that works. I've tried methods like collections, but it's really confusing for me. I bet this is really easy to do but I'm new to this so help appreciated.

Here is my code(Sorry for the giant list of embeds):

```
module.exports = {
name: 'quest',
aliases: ['q'],
cooldown: 12,
description: 'this offers a quest to the player',
execute(client, message, _args, Discord){

    if(message.member.roles.cache.has('975976810351304784')){
    const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#6655cc')
    .setTitle('What is the first building that was ever considered a monument?')
    .setAuthor({name: 'The Grinner', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})
    .setThumbnail('https://c.tenor.com/VFFI70gcJZwAAAAi/yoinkysploinky-jerma.gif')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({text: 'Provided by The Grinner!', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})


    const middleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#6655cc')
    .setTitle('Name the person who built the first carved-in mountain base.')
    .setAuthor({name: 'The Grinner', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})
    .setThumbnail('https://c.tenor.com/VFFI70gcJZwAAAAi/yoinkysploinky-jerma.gif')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({text: 'Provided by The Grinner!', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})
     
    const oldEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#6655cc')
    .setTitle('What currency was going to be implemented but was quickly abandoned in Boring Stasis?')
    .setAuthor({name: 'The Grinner', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})
    .setThumbnail('https://c.tenor.com/VFFI70gcJZwAAAAi/yoinkysploinky-jerma.gif')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({text: 'Provided by The Grinner!', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})

    const superoldEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#6655cc')
    .setTitle('Who destroyed the  monument in Boring Stasis?')
    .setAuthor({name: 'The Grinner', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})
    .setThumbnail('https://c.tenor.com/VFFI70gcJZwAAAAi/yoinkysploinky-jerma.gif')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({text: 'Provided by The Grinner!', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})

    const ancientEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#6655cc')
    .setTitle('Name the town in A New Beginning.')
    .setAuthor({name: 'The Grinner', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})
    .setThumbnail('https://c.tenor.com/VFFI70gcJZwAAAAi/yoinkysploinky-jerma.gif')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({text: 'Provided by The Grinner!', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})

    const bcEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#6655cc')
    .setTitle('What base was built above water and is known to be the largest base in Boring Stasis?')
    .setAuthor({name: 'The Grinner', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})
    .setThumbnail('https://c.tenor.com/VFFI70gcJZwAAAAi/yoinkysploinky-jerma.gif')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({text: 'Provided by The Grinner!', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})

    const ceEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#6655cc')
    .setTitle('Who was the communist in A New Beginning?')
    .setAuthor({name: 'The Grinner', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})
    .setThumbnail('https://c.tenor.com/VFFI70gcJZwAAAAi/yoinkysploinky-jerma.gif')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({text: 'Provided by The Grinner!', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})

    const adEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#6655cc')
    .setTitle('Name the cat who lived in the cafe in A New Beginning.')
    .setAuthor({name: 'The Grinner', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})
    .setThumbnail('https://c.tenor.com/VFFI70gcJZwAAAAi/yoinkysploinky-jerma.gif')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({text: 'Provided by The Grinner!', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})

    const bceEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#6655cc')
    .setTitle('Name the monument in Boring Stasis.')
    .setAuthor({name: 'The Grinner', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})
    .setThumbnail('https://c.tenor.com/VFFI70gcJZwAAAAi/yoinkysploinky-jerma.gif')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({text: 'Provided by The Grinner!', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})

    const supersuperoldEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#6655cc')
    .setTitle('When was the first realm created?')
    .setAuthor({name: 'The Grinner', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})
    .setThumbnail('https://c.tenor.com/VFFI70gcJZwAAAAi/yoinkysploinky-jerma.gif')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({text: 'Provided by The Grinner!', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})

    const longEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#6655cc')
    .setTitle('What realm was Homer first built in?')
    .setAuthor({name: 'The Grinner', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})
    .setThumbnail('https://c.tenor.com/VFFI70gcJZwAAAAi/yoinkysploinky-jerma.gif')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({text: 'Provided by The Grinner!', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})

    const shortEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#6655cc')
    .setTitle('')
    .setAuthor({name: 'The Grinner', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})
    .setThumbnail('https://c.tenor.com/VFFI70gcJZwAAAAi/yoinkysploinky-jerma.gif')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({text: 'Provided by The Grinner!', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awaitMessages` to get the correct answer and give some rewards.

```js
const quiz = require("../assets/quiz.json")
      const item = quiz[Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.length)];
      const filter = response => {
        return item.answers.some(answer => answer.toLowerCase() === response.content.toLowerCase());
      };

      const newEmbed = new MessageEmbed() 
// if these doesn't work, just add the Discord === Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#6655cc')
      .setTitle(`${item.question}`)
      .setAuthor({name: 'The Grinner', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})
      .setThumbnail('https://c.tenor.com/VFFI70gcJZwAAAAi/yoinkysploinky-jerma.gif')
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter({text: 'Provided by The Grinner!', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})


      message.reply({embeds: [newEmbed]}, {fetchReply: true})
        .then(() => {
            message.channel.awaitMessages({filter, max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time']})
        .then(collected => {
            message.channel.send(`${collected.first().author} got the correct answer!`)
        })
        .catch(collected => {
            message.channel.send(`Looks like nobody got the answer this time.\nThe correct answer is: **${item.answers}**`)
        })
    })
```

These is how it looks like with `awaitMessages`, Plus you can use only 1 embed to create your questions.

```js
[
    {
        "question" : "What is the first building that was ever considered a monument?",
        "answers" : ["Great Pyramid of Giza","Pyramid of Giza","Giza"]
    },
    {
        "question" : "What realm was Homer first built in?",
        "answers" : ["Homer"]
    }
]
```

And these is the `quiz.json` file, you can create an `array` to make a multiple answer or just one answer. You can see more `collector` here [Discord Collector](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-messages)

**Update:**

The code I already given is the type of `2 separated files`, And this is how it looks like when Its not `separated`

```js
const quiz = [
    {
        "question" : "What is the first building that was ever considered a monument?",
        "answers" : ["Great Pyramid of Giza","Pyramid of Giza","Giza"]
    },
    {
        "question" : "What realm was Homer first built in?",
        "answers" : ["Homer"]
    }
]
      const item = quiz[Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.length)];
      const filter = response => {
        return item.answers.some(answer => answer.toLowerCase() === response.content.toLowerCase());
      };

      const newEmbed = new MessageEmbed() 
// if these doesn't work, just add the Discord === Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#6655cc')
      .setTitle(`${item.question}`)
      .setAuthor({name: 'The Grinner', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})
      .setThumbnail('https://c.tenor.com/VFFI70gcJZwAAAAi/yoinkysploinky-jerma.gif')
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter({text: 'Provided by The Grinner!', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})


      message.reply({embeds: [newEmbed]}, {fetchReply: true})
        .then(() => {
            message.channel.awaitMessages({filter, max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time']})
        .then(collected => {
            message.channel.send(`${collected.first().author} got the correct answer!`)
        })
        .catch(collected => {
            message.channel.send(`Looks like nobody got the answer this time.\nThe correct answer is: **${item.answers}**`)
        })
    })
```

**Update:**

`Single square bracket in array`

```js
const quiz = [
        {
            "question": "What is the first building that was ever considered a monument?",
            "answers": ["The farm", "Water farm", "Farm", "farm"]
        },
        {
          "question": "Name the person who built the first carved-in mountain base.",
          "answers": ["Richard", "Richie Rich"]
    
        },
        {
          "question": "What currency was going to be implemented but was quickly abandoned in Boring Stasis?",
          "answers": ["Chumps", "Chump"]
    
        },
        {
            "question": "Who destroyed the monument in Boring Stasis?",
            "answers": ["Shorse"]
        },
        {
            "question": "Name the town in A New Beginning.",
            "answers": ["Sesame Street", "Sesamestreet", "sesame"]
        },
        {
            "question": "What base was built above water and is known to be the largest base in Boring Stasis?",
            "answers": ["Doom Base", "William's base", "Will base"]
        },
        {
            "question": "Who was the communist in A New Beginning?",
            "answers": ["Raimy", "NuttyHope"]
        },
        {
            "question": "Name the cat who lived in the cafe in A New Beginning.",
            "answers": ["Garfield"]
        },
        {
            "question": "Name the monument in Boring Stasis.",
            "answers": ["Michael B. Jordan"]
        },
        {
            "question": "When was the first realm created?",
            "answers": ["January"]
        },
        {
            "question": "What realm was Homer first built in?",
            "answers": ["Matthews Realm", "Matt Realm"]
        },
    
        {
            "question": "",
            "answers": ["HARD"]
        }
    
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! I put in the code and there is an error that says "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'answers')". Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed spell the `.json = answer`, Just change it to `answers`

Comment: `answer` to `answers`

Comment: Do you mind telling me where the line is that I have to change? Can't seem to find the one you're saying

Comment: The one file of your `questions` and `answer`

Comment: Look at the second snippet of this post

Comment: Ohhh I thought I was supposed to combine the questions and answers with the same file and not make them separate, let me try that

Comment: You can do it like that too. Let me update my answer

Comment: I update my answer, you can check it now

Comment: Okay so everything works except the bot reads the .setTitle part as undefined and it doesn't actually send the question

Comment: It actually works for me, Can you share your code on how you put all the code at once?

Comment: Sure let me edit my post

Comment: Ah it would be a undefined because every `questions and answers` has a `square bracket`, remember that if you going to create an `array` you only need to use `1 square bracket`, check my edit post you'll see how to create an `array`

Comment: Always welcome! Glad it worked.